# Can't import ng2-select SelectComponent

Tags: javascript, angular, select

I'm trying to fix an issues in `valor-software` library `ng2-select` after install it in my node_modules ( `npm install --save ng2-select` ), I want to inject a `SelectComponent` as Child using `@ViewChild` but I get always undefined.
its appear really trivial, I have seen comments in github of the project and it seems work for many people.
I'm on `angular/CLI project` if I shoud add more information please mention it in comments. thanks .

```
node_modules
    |
    + --ng2-select
        |
        +--ng2-select.d.ts
        |
        +--select/
            |
            +--select.d.ts
            |
            +-- ...
```

gn2-select.d.ts content

```
export * from './select/common';
export * from './select/off-click';
export * from './select/select.module';
export * from './select/select';
export * from './select/select-interfaces';
export * from './select/select-item';
export * from './select/select-pipes';
```

content of select/select.d.ts

```
export declare class SelectComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor        {
     private sanitizer;
     .....
}
```

mycomponent :

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { SelectComponent }  from 'ng2-select';

export class SubSystemComponent implements OnInit {
 @ViewChild('SelectComponent') 
private sysSearchInput: SelectComponent;

  constructor(private sysService : SubSysService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.sysSearchInput);

  }
```

Comment: You should implement `AfterViewInit` instead of `OnInit`. (or both, but you won't be able to acces it until AfterViewInit). the [doc is very clear about that](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChild-decorator.html).

Comment: I shoud check the value of  'this.sysSearchInput' in 'AfterViewInit' Method ?

Comment: definitely, yes.

Comment: unfortunately that was not the error because even checked after 'ngAfterViewInit' and button click the component has always udefined value

Comment: `"SelectComponent"` is not a valid selector, `SelectComponent` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should access your `@ViewChild` in the `ngAfterViewInit` method, it is not set yet when `ngOnInit` is called, see the [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChild-decorator.html):

> View queries are set before the `ngAfterViewInit` callback is called.
>
> ```
> import {AfterViewInit, Component, Directive, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
> @Directive({selector: 'child-directive'})
> class ChildDirective {
> }
> @Component({selector: 'someCmp', templateUrl: 'someCmp.html'})
> class SomeCmp implements AfterViewInit {
>   @ViewChild(ChildDirective) child: ChildDirective;
>   ngAfterViewInit() {
>     // child is set
>   }
> }
> ```

You can also take a look at the [Lifecycle Hooks](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html)

You should also use the class reference and not a string, as strings are for targeting `ElementRef`, not components:

```
@ViewChild('SelectComponent') // invalid
@ViewChild(SelectComponent) // valid
```

Comment: unfortunately that was not the error because even checked after `ngAfterViewInit`  and button click the component has always udefined value

Comment: ah Ok Thanks @n00dl3 i'll try